# Ver datos de una curva al colocar el cursor sobre el objeto, utilizando HoverTools

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, bokeh

Intento conseguir, utilizando la herramienta HoverTools de Boken, acceder a datos de una curva, colocando el cursor en cualquier punto de ella. Lo intento de dos formas diferentes pero no lo consigo con ninguna de ellas.

Importación de datos a un dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

dicc_tickers = {"Iberdrola":"IBE.MC", "Telefonica":"TEF.MC", "Renta4":"R4.MC", "Ibex35":"^IBEX", "S&P500":"^GSPC", 
                "Nasdaq":"^IXIC", "Nikkey_225":"^N225", "DowJons":"^DJI", "Eurostoxx50":"^STOXX50E", 
               "Iberdrola":"IBE.MC", "Iberdrola":"IBE.MC", "Iberdrola":"IBE.MC", "Iberdrola":"IBE.MC", 
               "Apple":'AAPL', "Microsoft":'MSFT', "Google":'GOOG', "EUR/USD":"EURUSD=X"}

from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import datetime

def get(tickers, startdate, enddate):
    def data(ticker):
        return (pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo' ))
    datas = map (data, tickers)
    return(pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker', 'Date']))

startdate = "2000-1-4"
enddate = "2020-10-30"
#tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'IBM', 'GOOG', "IBE.MC", "TEF.MC"]
tickers = dicc_tickers.values()
cotizaciones = get(tickers, datetime.datetime(2006, 10, 1), datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1))
datos_yahoo = cotizaciones[['Adj Close']].reset_index().pivot('Date', 'Ticker', 'Adj Close')
```

**OPCION 1:**

```
from bokeh.plotting import output_notebook, figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

output_notebook()
df = datos_yahoo["2016-1-4":"2020-10-30"].reset_index()
# Convert to ColumnDataSource
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
hover = HoverTool(names=["AAPL"])
p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', plot_width=600, plot_height=300, tools=[hover,])
plot.line(x='Date', y='AAPL', name="AAPL", source=source)
output_notebook()
show(plot)
```

**OPCION 2**

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
import pandas as pd
import os

#p = figure(toolbar_location="left", tools="pan,wheel_zoom,lasso_select,tap,undo,reset", [hover,])
#p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300, tools=[hover,])
p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300, tools=[hover,])

df = datos_yahoo["2016-1-4":"2020-10-30"].reset_index()

# Convert to ColumnDataSource
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
                 
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ( 'Date',   '@Date{%F}'            ),
        ( 'AAPL',  '$@{adj close}{%0.2f}' ) ], 
    formatters={
        '@Date'        : 'datetime', # use 'datetime' formatter for '@date' field
        '@{AAPL}' : 'printf',   # use 'printf' formatter for '@{adj close}' field
                                     # use default 'numeral' formatter for other fields
    },

    # display a tooltip whenever the cursor is vertically in line with a glyph
    mode='vline'
)

plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
plot.line(x='Date', y='AAPL', name="AAPL", source=source)

output_notebook()
show(plot)
```

Es evidente que no acabo de entender la clase HoverTool. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda para superar este problema y entender cómo se aplica esta herramienta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hHe encontrado un solución alternativa, utilizando la libreria Python-Bokeh.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_bokeh
pandas_bokeh.output_notebook()

data = datos_yahoo[["R4.MC", "TEF.MC", "IBE.MC"]].copy(deep=True)["2016":"2020"]

data.plot_bokeh.line(
    figsize=(800, 450),
    title="Apple vs Google",
    xlabel="Date",
    ylabel="Stock price [$]",
    yticks=[0, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    ylim=(0, 10),
    xlim=("2016-01-04", "2020-10-01"),
    colormap=["red", "blue", "green"],
    plot_data_points=True,
    plot_data_points_size=0.8 )
```

Aunque mantengo las dudas planteadas en la pregunta y me gustaría saber como hacerlo con la librería normal Bokeh.